# How to unwrap a chain of Optionals from PFUser to access a Boolean value

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am having an issue with one `if` statement in Swift 2 among with Parse.com SDK.

So I have the `_Users` table and there I have one boolean which is `something` so if this something is `true` I want to show a segment control button. But if it is false I want it to be 0.1 width (cause I can't delete it) and to disable it.
The segment control item that I want to disable is the `0` and the `1` should stay open for all of the users.

My code is this

```
let modifiedStatus = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("something")?.boolValue

    if PFUser.currentUser() != nil && modifiedStatus == false {

        recipesSegControl.setWidth(0.1, forSegmentAtIndex: 0)
        recipesSegControl.setEnabled(false, forSegmentAtIndex: 0)


    }
```

So I put it on viewDidLoad and I have the following problem.

When I login with a user that has `FALSE` boolean it doesnt show the `segment control 0`

And if I logout and login on the same time (without closing the application or anything) with a user which has `TRUE` boolean 
it prints the condition `nil` and it hides the `segment control 0` as if it was `FALSE` user.

Also tried the code to the `ViewDidAppear` with no success.
What am I doing wrong here? Am I missing something?

The `if` block is also used in another swift file(in the same application, for the same concept) exactly like this and it works perfect all the time.

Comment: Instead of doing everything in one statement, how about checking the individual items to see why you're getting FALSE behaviour?  Do you have a current user?  If you do, what is `objectForKey` returning?  ....

Comment: @PhillipMills Yes i have a current user and as i say in my question, when i logout and i do an instant login with another account (without closing the app) i get `nil` as objectForKey instead of `TRUE` which is on the parse.com class as i see it on the dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not dealing with Optionals properly. Once you safely unwrap and handle the failure cases, all will become clear.

```
    if let user = PFUser.currentUser() {
        if let modifiedStatus = user.objectForKey("something")?.boolValue {
            if modifiedStatus {
               print("modifiedStatus is true, acting accordingly")
               // enable the recipesSegControl, I guess?
            }
            else {
               // this is the disabling code, right?
               print("modifiedStatus is false, acting accordingly")
               recipesSegControl.setWidth(0.1, forSegmentAtIndex: 0)
               recipesSegControl.setEnabled(false, forSegmentAtIndex: 0)
            }
        }
        else {
            print("modifiedStatus is nil -- neither false nor true -- what should I do?")
        }
    }
    else {
        print("No current user present!")
    }
```

Comment: So i modified your code to make enable and to set proper width to the segment control if the user is `TRUE` and it's all fine now. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

With a `guard` statement you can check the `Optional` values and the status in a single line:

```
func test() { // wrapping in a function so guard can return
  guard PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("something")?.boolValue == false else {
    // handle the error here
    return // In a guard statement you need to return, break, continue, or throw
  }

  recipesSegControl.setWidth(0.1, forSegmentAtIndex: 0)
  recipesSegControl.setEnabled(false, forSegmentAtIndex: 0)
}
```